# AVFoundation - Is it possible to see how much of a video stream has buffered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video-streaming, avfoundation

I was wondering if there was a property or method on any of the AVPlayer classes that tells me what percentage (or what CMTime/CMTimeRange) of my streaming video is playable/buffered onto the device?

I've looked in `AVPlayer`, `AVURLAsset`, and `AVPlayerItem`. I haven't found anything that looks like it would help, except maybe the `seekableTimeRanges` method.

Thanks for any and all help.